# Logic behind communication between controllers in javax

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am newbie and learning java and javafx.

Is there any source that you can suggest or can you explain me briefly the logic behind controllers communication in javafx.

I have made a program which has two controllers and corresponding fxml files.

MainController.java

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label mainL;
    @FXML
    private Button mainB;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {


        FXMLLoader popupLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Popup.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent)popupLoader.load();
        PopupController popupCont = popupLoader.getController();
        popupCont.changeLabel("The Second");
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Popup Window");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();


    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

}
```

PopupController.java

```
public class PopupController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label secondaryL;
    @FXML
    private Button secondB;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    public void changeLabel(String s){
        secondaryL.setText(s);
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {


        Stage stage = (Stage) secondB.getScene().getWindow();

        stage.close();


    }
}
```

In Main window, I have **mainL** label, and **mainB** button.
When mainB button is clicked Popup window opens up with a **secondaryL** label and button (**secondB**). It also changes the secondaryL text from "Secondary Label" to "the Second".
And when the secondB button clicked here, it closes window and leaves you with Main window.
What I need here when secondB clicked not only it should close the window but it also should change the text of mainL label.

I somehow cannot figure out the logic here.
I can understand when I open new window I can send send some parameters here or run method here. But once I am in new window (main window still there behind) I cannot access main controller anymore.
I know I can create a new instance of Main controller and work on it but, this is not what I want. I want the very same main window components to be changed. Like the mainL from secondary controller.

Can anyone explain what logic shall I use here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass a reference to your first controller into your second controller. There are a couple steps to make this work.

> PopupController.java

First, add an instance reference to your `MainController` into your `PopupController.java` class:

```
private MainController mainController;
```

Add a setter:

```
public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
    this.mainController = mainController;
}
```

> MainController.java

Now you need to pass your `MainController` to the `PopupController` using the new setter:

private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

```
FXMLLoader popupLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Popup.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent) popupLoader.load();
PopupController popupCont = popupLoader.getController();
popupCont.setMainController(this);      // This passes this controller reference to your popup
popupCont.changeLabel("The Second");
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("Popup Window");
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.show();
```

}

You now have the proper reference. So now when closing your `PopupController`, just call the `setMainL()` method using the reference to the `MainController`:

```
mainController.setMainL("the First!");
Stage stage = (Stage) secondB.getScene().getWindow();
stage.close();
```

**What's Happening?**

This is a fairly common usage in JavaFX. You cannot access one class from another without first obtaining a reference *to* that class; this simply provides that reference for you to use.

Comment: Could you please explain me what are we doing with this piece of code. 'popupCont.setMainController(this);' ?

Comment: The `this` keyword always refers to the current instance of the class. So, since it was called from the `MainController` class, it refers to that instance of the `MainController`.  When we pass `this` to the `PopupController`, it is sending the same `MainController`, essentially; this means you do not need to create a new controller and can continue working with the `MainController` you already have.  Make sense?

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Awesome. Thanks for your help.